# Preview in designer wpf DataGrid DataGridTemplateColumn column

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to preview in the XAML designer how my DataGridTemplateColumn will looks like ?

Example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="2" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/WpfImages;component/images/16x16/wheels.png"
                                Width="16" Height="16" ToolTip="Show wheels" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a design-time data context bound to a design-time specific ViewModel to have data displayed in the IDE while you code your UI.

MSDN has a pretty comprehensive article on it here: [(clicky!)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn169081.aspx)

Comment: When I tried this, it only seemed to work for auto-generated columns.  Non-auto-generated columns still appear blank for me.